# Creating Chart using measures in Power BI

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a pie chart to show the number of each rate. However, I am not able to put the measure into the value field.

So I have two tables.

List table

[image]

| No |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| B1 |
| B2 |

Result table

[image]

| Name | Year | No | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022 | A1 | Good |
| ABC | 2022 | B2 | Good |
| ABC | 2021 | A2 | Not Good |
| DEF | 2022 | A1 | Not Good |
| GHI | 2022 | B1 | Good |

What I want

[image]

| Name | Year | No | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2021 | A1 | ok |
| ABC | 2021 | A2 | Not good |
| ABC | 2021 | A3 | ok |
| ABC | 2021 | B1 | ok |
| ABC | 2021 | B2 | ok |
| ABC | 2022 | A1 | Good |
| ABC | 2022 | A2 | ok |
| ABC | 2022 | A3 | ok |
| ABC | 2022 | B1 | ok |
| ABC | 2022 | B2 | Good |
| DEF | 2022 | A1 | Not good |
| DEF | 2022 | A2 | ok |
| DEF | 2022 | A3 | ok |
| DEF | 2022 | B1 | ok |
| DEF | 2022 | B2 | ok |
| GHI | 2022 | A1 | ok |
| GHI | 2022 | A2 | ok |
| GHI | 2022 | A3 | ok |
| GHI | 2022 | B1 | Good |
| GHI | 2022 | B2 | ok |

So to achieve what I want, I crossjoin the two tables.

```
Table = CROSSJOIN('List Table',SELECTCOLUMNS('Result Table', "Name", 'Result Table'[Name]))
```

And also added a key column to each table where I join name+year+clause. Then I can only choose many to many relationship.

To show ok, i created a measure where

```
if (HASONEVALUE('Result Table'[Rate]), min('Result Table'[Rate]) , "ok")
```

My process might be wrong too so any idea?

Comment: Please don't paste data as a picture. You should also mark your old questions as solved...

Comment: @DavidBacci I have formatted the data

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are trying to do better, I think I would do this from Power Query instead of DAX. You are going to have to jump through hoops to do the crossjoin, and composite keys, and relationships, and a measure. It will drive extra calculation for every report and will be slow if you have a lot of data.

In Power Query, it will take a little longer to load, but then perform faster in the reports and the data model will be clean and simple. Do the crossjoins to get the combination of Name, Year, and No, then merge in the rates you have. Then just replace nulls with "ok".

A crossjoin in Power Query needs a distinct column like this `Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Data,"Name"))`. Then you add a column that is a table of distinct values `Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Data,"Year")))`. When you expand this column, you have a crossjoin.

```
let
    Source = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Data,"Name")),
    #"Added Distinct Years" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Data,"Year"))),
    #"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Distinct Years", "Year", {"Year"}, {"Year"}),
    #"Added Distinct No" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Year", "Custom", each Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Data,"No"))),
    #"Expanded No" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Distinct No", "Custom", {"No"}, {"No"}),
    #"Merged with Data" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded No", {"Name", "No", "Year"}, Data, {"Name", "No", "Year"}, "Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Rate" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged with Data", "Data", {"Rate"}, {"Rate"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Rate",null,"ok",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Rate"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. Would you be able to provide the file so that I can understand better? Thank you in advance!